# How does ようにして work when followed by a verb/al?

Tags: grammar

Off these excerpts from [夢十夜](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000148/files/799_14972.html):

A 「田圃｛たんぼ｝へかかったね」と背中で云った。

B 「どうして解る」と顔を後うしろへ振り向ける**ようにして**聞いたら、

A 「だって鷺｛さぎ｝が鳴くじゃないか」と答えた。

"asked **by** turning my head towards my back"?

この時代の藁沓は深いものであった。立つと膝頭｛ひざがしら｝まで来た。その端｛はし｝の所は藁｛わら｝を少し編残｛あみのこ｝して、房のように下げて、歩くとばらばら動く**ようにして**、飾りとしていた。

"decorated **in the manner of**"?

How does ようにして work in general?

Comment: In general, "so that ...." or "as if ..." will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have ***two very different*** usages of 「ようにして」 here.

> 「[顔]{かお}をうしろへ[振]{ふ}り[向]{む}け る**ようにして**[聞]{き}いた」
>
> "asked **by** turning my head towards my back"?

***Yes*** if you mean he turned his head just a little, but ***no*** if you mean he turned his head around anywhere close to 180 degrees.

「ように」 was used because he did **not** turn his head that much.  Here, 「よう」= "like".

Had he actually turned anywhere completely around, the author would have used a phrase like 「振り向けて聞いた」 without  「ようにして」.

> 「[歩]{ある}くとばらばら[動]{うご}く**ようにして**、[飾]{かざ}りとしていた」
>
> "decorated in the manner of"?

Not exactly, but the "in the manner of" part is not far off.  A more versatile translation of 「ように」 in this context would be "**so that**".

”They made the top part so that it rustled when you walked and they (also) used it (the top part) as a decoration."

> How does ようにして work in general?

That is too broad a question, really, but what @user4092 says in the comment above summarizes it well -- "so that" and "as if".  Those should work at least most of the time.

The meaning mostly depends on the relationship between the two verb phrases that sandwich 「ようにして」.